# Adding objects to RLMArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, realm

I have classes

```
//Ingredient.h
@interface Ingredient : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *name;

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Ingredient)

//Recipe.h
@interface Recipe : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) RLMArray<Ingredients *>< Ingredients> *ingredients;

@end
```

Is it the correct to add multiple ingredients?

```
Ingredient *tomato = [[Ingredient alloc] init];
tomato.name = @"tomato";
Ingredient *onion = [[Ingredient alloc] init];
onion = @"onion";

Recipe *recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];

[realm beginWriteTransaction]
[recipe.ingredients add:tomato];
[recipe.ingredients add:onion];
[realm.commitWriteTransaction];
```

Is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close! `RLMArray` follows `NSMutableArray`'s method naming convention.

So the correct method name is

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction]
[recipe.ingredients addObject:tomato];
[recipe.ingredients addObject:onion];
[realm.commitWriteTransaction];
```

Check out [`RLMArray`'s documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html) for a complete list of methods you can use. For example, a more streamlined way to add objects could be:

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction]
[recipe.ingredients addObjects:@[tomato, onion]];
[realm.commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: Thanks! And I guess `tomato` will automatically be added to `realm`?

Comment: Yep! If the object doesn't already belong to an `RLMRealm`, calling `addObject` on it will add it.